# Admob not working - Android

Tags: android, admob

Okay so I am trying to add Admob to my app and I am having an issue. I downloaded the jar file and everything that is needed. I made an admob account and have my app linked but the problem is that I want to display an interstitial ad on my app and when I followed the google tutorial there is a line of code that is this

```
 // Create the interstitial
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this, MY_INTERSTITIAL_UNIT_ID);
```

I don't know what MY_INTERSTITIAL_UNIT_ID is. I downloaded the complete google code to see what they did and this is what they have

```
 // Create an ad.
    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this, AD_UNIT_ID_GOES_HERE);
```

So clearly AD_UNIT_ID_GOES_HERE is some code I am suppose to have? Or what? Because the variable is not defined in the google example.

Can someone please tell me how this part works.

Comment: Visit www.admob.com and register yourself over there.

Answer (score 0):

It is your `AD_UNIT_ID`. Read the [docs](https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/3016009?hl=en)

Also make sure you have read all the steps in the [Before You Start](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/) section.